# Derivative of the product of a Heaviside/indicator function with another function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-distributions

Let $ \Omega \subsetneq \Omega ^ \Box $ be open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and a function $f \in C^1(\Omega ^\Box)$.

I was wondering if the following holds true (in the sense of distributions):

$$ (\mathbb{1}_\Omega f)'= \mathbb{1}_\Omega f' \text{  in }  \Omega ^ \Box,$$

where $\mathbb{1}_\Omega $ is the indicator function of $\Omega$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

I am an engineer, and I am solving an applied problem in which the above question poped up. I try with the definition of the generalized derivative and find that they are not equal. This really makes me confused, since my intuition tells me that they should be equal.

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, seems that it's not true. Take for example $\mathbb{R}$, you have
$$(\mathcal{1}_{(0, +\infty]} f)' = \mathcal{1}_{(0, +\infty]}f' + \delta_{0}f.$$
So in the point of discontinuity you have an explosion, the same should be in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, Hello :-)

Comment: I have a follow-up question: is there any operator/transformation $T$ such that:
$$ T[(\mathbb{1}_\Omega f)']= \mathbb{1}_\Omega f' \text{  in }  \Omega ^ \Box  \text{?}$$

Comment: Alright, it's better, but you probably want this equality for every differentiable $f$, don't you? Moreover you would probably like to have some "nice" properties of this operator. And finally why do you even need such operator?

Comment: Yes, for every differentiable $f$.

Comment: Thanks! Just because I am implementing a numerical method for solving PDEs, and it turns out that in the formulation I need the equality, or at least a best approximation. Two other options: I wish $T$ is something touchable/approximable such that 
 $$ (T[\mathbb{1}_\Omega f])'= \mathbb{1}_\Omega f' \text{  in }  \Omega ^ \Box  $$ or $$ (\mathbb{1}_\Omega T[f])'= \mathbb{1}_\Omega f' \text{  in }  \Omega ^ \Box  $$

Comment: Ah, I see. So let me give simple example in  $\mathbb{R}$, that may probably help. Take a function $\varphi(x) = \alpha exp(-\frac{1}{(x-1)^2})$, and consider a sequence of functions $\varphi_\epsilon(x) = \frac{1}{\epsilon}\varphi(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$, this sequence is a good approximation to Dirac when epsilon goes to zero. And a primitive of this sequence is a good approximation for Heaviside step function.

Comment: Where $\alpha$ is such that $\int \varphi(x) dx = 1$. So in $\mathbb{R}^2$ must be methods like this. That is why you probably want to work with an approximation of your indicator function and not approximation of $f$, since only indicator is not continuous. Hope it helps, unfortunately I'm not a specialist in functional analysis.

Comment: Thank you, Hello! I will think about it :-)